# Como usar Punteros en Matrices

Tags: c

Yo tengo una matriz A[3][10] pero quiero acceder al espacio de memoria de esa matriz con punteros.La tengo inicializada de la siguiente manera:

```
a=A;
b=B;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        *a=0;
        *b=0;
        a++;
        b++;
    }
}
```

Normalmente usaba un scanf para acceder a los elementos de la matriz pero con punteros no tengo idea, alguien me puede ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes una matriz con este aspecto:

```
tipo A[3][10];
```

Significa que tienes una matriz de dos dimensiones. La primera dimensión tiene tres elementos y su tipo es `tipo (*)[10]`, la segunda dimensión tiene diez elementos y su tipo es `tipo *`. Así que puedes usar estos punteros:

```
int (*a)[10] = A;

for (int y = 0; y != 3; ++y)
{
    int *b = *a;
    for (int x = 0; x != 10; ++x)
    {
        printf("El elemento [%d][%d] es %d\n", y, x, *b);
        ++b;
    }
    ++a;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc/LboMwEAXQtf0V01SReLVihr4imkpZ9CsoCwJOi0RMRUgFivh2eh2qLq6M7XNtU96VTWE/5/m2tmVzrgy9nvqqbu@/3rSubU/HorbeT1tXvr5o5VZ2WZJnHOe0pQvFEREjgiTIA/KIPCHPyAuyibRSikEZlEEZlEEZlEEZlEF5oQIqoAIqoAIqoAIqoAIqG5pSvbzICwr/70U7t3ZoO/LcxoiVOMVws6UkpTAcfa3wG9dWsMduUKSY/heGpTC4AseuMaBxrajvDuLgrd4bMo05Gtu3lK2r3IXMidbVh11FNEY0RDjcdwerMNy7cdLu09014X2d6c@dxUV6mudf)</kbd>.